# Expected value with probabilities

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, random-variables

Joel owns a lawn care business and recently performed some research on the size of 50 lawns that he takes care of.
Joel recalls that he is expected to take care of a total of $21$ acres of lawn for every $6$ customers that he serves. He also knows that he has $4$ customers with $1$ acre of lawn, $6$ customers with $2$ acres of lawn, and $9$ customers with $5$ acres of lawn.
Unfortunately, Joel can’t find the information on the number of customers that have $3$ or $4$ acre lawns.
**Find the 2 missing numbers.**

**Acres of Lawn**        **Customer**

1                                            4
2                                            6
3                                            ?
4                                            ?
5                                            9
 
**Total**                                   **50**

**My try to this problem** 
The Total number of Customer are 19 out of 50 so the remaining customer is $31$ for Lawn $3,4$ so to fit $31$ customers in lawn $3$ and $4$ I have used probability. So, out of two lawns, the chances of one lawn to come up is $0.5$
Therefore $31\times 0.5=15.5$.
So I am getting $15.5$ customer  each for lawn $3$ and $4$.
Please help me where I am making mistakes and how many number of customer are there in lawn $3$ and lawn $4$.

Comment: You know that $n_3+n_4 = 50-(4+6+9) = 31$. You know that ${1 \over 50} \sum_k n_k A_k = {21 \over 6}$, which gives another equation involving the unknowns $n_3,n_4$. Solve for $n_3,n_4$.

Comment: yeah got it thanks for help

Comment: @CY5 I edited my answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**
Probability isn't part of this question.
"He is expected to take care of a total of $21$ acres of lawn for every $6$ customers" - this means that the total acres of lawn should be $$21\div6=3.5$$ times the number of customers.
Can you take it from here?

**EDIT:**
The total acres of lawn is $1$ acre times $4$ customers, $2$ acres times $6$ customers, $3$ acres times $x$ customers and so on.
Thus the total acres of lawn is
$$1\times4+2\times6+3x+4y+5\times9$$
and this equals $3.5$ times the number of customers:
$$3.5\times50$$

Comment: @CY5 I think you missed the $\frac1{50}$ part.